# Click an element of a hover button which hide/unhide to expand other selections

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to login on a company website to upload a file. I am successful on login process but I failed on selecting the "Text button" that expands the other selection.

[enter image description here][1]

Below is the HTML elements.

```html
<div class="tree_margin" id="tree_root/14+" style="text-decoration: none; display: block;">&nbsp;
<a class="tree_hover" href="JavaScript:tree_switch_folder('tree_root/14+');">
<img src="skin/blue/sidemenu_minus.jpg" border="0" alt="資材システム" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;資材システム</a><br></div>
```

資材システム

I tried the code below but it gives me "error:438".

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Document.getElementByClassId("tree_root/14+").Click
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should find the `<a>` element and click it, not the `<div>` element. I agree with QHarr's answer and you can try it to see if it can work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have left a sufficient page load wait, and that you have shown the correct html, I believe you want to click the anchor tag. You can target its class via css class selector and the `querySelector()` method:

```
objIE.Document.querySelector(".tree_hover").click
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, I tried itbut Error:438 still persist. All the hover buttons has the element <a>class=tree_hover. The distinct element for the button I want to click is only the id="tree_root/14+".  When I copy the Xpath this is what comes out //*[@id="tree_root/14+"]/a. Sorry I'm just starting to use HTML.

Comment: `objIE.Document.querySelector("[id='tree_root/14+']").click` ? Have you checked element is not inside an iframe/frame? Also, does stepping through code with F8 resolve the error?

Comment: I think it is inside a Frame. What difference will it make? <frame name="IM_MENU" bordercolor="#FF0000" scrolling="auto" src="system(2f)security(2f)user(2f)600(2f)standard(5f)menu(5f)frame.jssps?im_mark=b-kc76p8*9zvo7m&amp;im_from=system(2f)security(2f)user(2f)600(2f)main&amp;id=leftFrame&amp;bordercolor=%23FF0000&amp;frameborder=no&amp;scrolling=auto&amp;name=IM_MENU" frameborder="no" id="leftFrame">

Comment: This is the full XPath /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div[112]/a . I used F8 to step through the code to make sure the page has loaded completely but there's still an error.

Comment: you would need to first do something like `objIE.Document.getElementById("leftFrame").contentDocument.querySelector("[id='tree_root/14+']").click`